# PHP script keeps timing out (nginx 504 gateway error)

Tags: php, nginx, timeout

I am running a very large script (importing data from a CSV file to a database). The CSV file contains thousands of rows, hence why the script times out.

The script is also being run on a shared-server (if this helps).

I have tried changing the `max_execution_time` to 60, `set_time_limit` to 0 (and 300) and finally I tried using `ignore_user_abort(true)` to check if this continues the script after the user aborts.

Could somebody please advise?

Thank you

Comment: When you say a shared server, is that where your host provider controls most of the settings of php and the environment? If that's the case your best bet would be to open a ticket with them. Can you run your script in CL-mode (command line)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes I think that's where they keep their PHP settings. I can't overwrite certain php.ini settings (only few), nor can I find a config for nginx. I do have Shell Access? However this isn't ideal as the script will be executed by my client (not a developer)

Answer (score 0):

Execute the script from your SSH shell. Like:  php yourfile.php. Then you won't endup with this timeout shizzles.